# Paypal PRO integration with Cakephp (or just php)

Tags: cakephp, plugins, paypal

I have a website running with CakePHP 1.3.10, and I need to implement a payment solution for the articles there (please note that it's not a "shopping cart" centric website, but some articles can be bought).

I want to use PayPal PRO for total integration in the website, but I've never done anything like that. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction about how to do implement this. I've been looking in PayPal's developer website, but I can't find a simple PHP example. Also, I've looked for CakePHP plugins that handle this but what I've found seems outdated or not what I'm looking for.

I already have a PayPal Sandbox account to be able to start testing right away (once I implement something of course ;P)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this one... just change all the credentials on the plugin
[Paypal Website Payments Pro Component for CakePHP 2.2.X](https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal)